# Does the fact that a job is part-time show up on employment history check?

Tags: background-check, employment, part-time

For those working part-time jobs, if they do not specify that it's part-time on their resume, would an employment history check reveal that the job is part-time and not fulltime?

Comment: What sort of "employment history check" are you referring to?  In the US, a potential private employer would generally have no way to determine this other than asking the previous employer.  That previous employer might or might not answer such a question but I would expect that most employers would.

Comment: If you're planning on lying about it because you think part-time work doesn't look as good, the answer is that outright lying about an easily-checked fact is seldom a good idea. Instead, prepare to explain why you were working part time.

Comment: @StuartF not planning to lie, just planning to omit that detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received copies of several past background checks. None that I've seen asked whether the jobs were full or part-time. Nowadays, when questioning prior employers, the checkers tend to stick to the following questions:

1. Did JobHunter69 work for you?
2. What dates?
3. Is JobHunter69 eligible for rehire?

Sometimes, they ask for what your starting and finishing job title(s) were.

The "is eligible for rehire" is the way to ask "were they fired?" Which one cannot ask (in America) in these litigious times. One of my previous employers stated "due to company policy, no one is eligible for rehire".

At no time do they ask "how much did JobHunter69 get paid?" No one would answer that.

Some background checking firms use credit reporting agencies to track employment history. Did you use this job as a reference when applying for credit? If so, that could show up.

Generally, companies check for things that they've had problems with. One (financial) company that a previous employer dealt with had previous problems with unlicensed drivers, so that background check cared more about auto insurance and driving license issues more than it dealt with prior criminal behavior.

Background checks for security clearances are far more in depth.

Answer (score 5):

> would an employment history check reveal that the job is part-time and not fulltime?

Yes, a BG check could surely reveal this and other information about your past jobs. It could even show jobs that you didn't list explicitly on your resume, depending on how thorough the BG check is.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any expectation that your resume contains all the information about your job history. People feel free to leave jobs off their resume if they are not relevant, and explicitly stating "part time" isn't necessary as long as you don't mislead (though it might be a good idea).

When someone does a background check they usually ask again for complete details of your job history, and at that point you are expected to list every job and give all the details they ask for. If the background check find a discrepancy between what you gave them at this stage and what they find that might be a cause for concern.